# AngularJS select required validation

Tags: angularjs, select, required

Following is my code snippet. I want to validate my select box using angular.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <select name="category_1"  ng-model="catid" id="category_1" ng-options="category.catid for catid in categories" required>
    <option value="" selected=""></option>
    <option value="1">music</option>
    <option value="2">internet</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but can not submit the form I got this error in chrome,,and submit button is not working

> An invalid form control with name='category_0' is not focusable.

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/06s0uJUp2K7B571OtJ8A?p=preview)

Comment: `category.catid for catid in categories`: that is invalid. What is `category`?

Comment: how can I make it valid?

Comment: `category.catid for category in categories`would be valid, assuming the onjects in categories have a field named catid. Why don't you read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions?

Comment: because of my english is not enough, I have tried that and now I can not click the submit button

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the select box, maybe the problem is that you have another select box (with name `category_0`) or other input field (with name `category_0`), which has the **required** attribute and it is hidden or is not visible.

So when you try to submit your form, it tries to focus it, but is not possible. Make sure that the element with name `category_0` is not inside an `ng-hide` block, or inside an `ng-show` with a `false` condition.